# Why is this website so slow on mobile [shopify]

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to help a client with their slow-ish website https://www.dp-tools.de. If I use Google page speed for mobile I can see that it takes 7 seconds to be interactive but nothing in the found problems really tells me why it is actually that slow. I also tried chrome lighthouse and couldn't really see all that much.

Is there another way of checking or maybe anyone here sees why it is so slow?

Answer (score 1):

Open up the client's Shopify Admin, and examine the theme. Does it have any strange slow code in it? Examine the Apps installed that directly affect theme. Are any of them crap, old, broken junk?

The best way to debug a slow theme is to just start hacking out any junk the client may have added to their theme. A lot of themes are so bad, for example, they load jQuery 3 times. Likely you have one bad apple in there, a call that is blocking and takes way to long to timeout or respond. Developer tools can point these out to in your console. Mobile versions have to come with a developer console you can inspect too right?